# imported class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to eclipse and jsp. I tried a lot to import class in jsp file but getting this error continuously.

```
An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
DateDemo cannot be resolved to a type
```

I googled but not getting where to put my class. Below is the structure and code-

src->beans-> DateDemo.java

```
package beans;


    import java.util.*;
    public class DateDemo{
    public Date returnDate() {
    Date d=new Date();
    return d;
    }
    }
```

WebContent->index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register here..!!!</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="beans.DateDemo"%>


    <% DateDemo demo = new DateDemo();
    out.println("Current date : " + demo.returnDate());
    %> 

</body>
</html>
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: clean the project and stop the server and try again.

Comment: not getting option of clean after right clicking on project. How to clean it?

Comment: Eclipse menu bar - Project -> clean

Comment: Finally it's working..Thanks a lot..I wasted 2 hrs to solve this but couldn't solve it. Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP seems totally right.  Please check your web application packaging (the WAR archive if you are packagin it like that, or an open directory if it is your format) and make sure that there is at least this:

```
.../wherever_your_app_is/index.jsp
.../wherever_your_app_is/WEB-INF/web.xml
.../wherever_your_app_is/WEB-INF/classes/beans/DateDemo.class
```

This is the minimum set of files you need to run your web application, if all of this is in place you should have no problem

Comment: .../wherever_your_app_is/WEB-INF/classes/beans/DateDemo.class this is not available. my class is available in .../wherever_your_app_is/src/beans/DateDemo.class .  Now what should I do ?

Comment: The binary should get packaged where I have told you.  Please tell me how are you packaging your app.  Does your IDE do it for you or are you managing it by some other means?

Comment: It seems DateDemo.class is not available. IDE should maintain it but it is not creating. Only DateDemo.java is available. What should I do so that IDE maintainn it automatically ?

Comment: Thank you jorge for quick reply. I cleaned the project and issue get resolved.